# Grabbing values from HTML with BS4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having a hard time figuring out how to grab certain data from this HTML snippet that I've obtained from parsing through HTML via BeautifulSoup.

Here is my code:

```
productpage = 'http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/26133/adidas-samba-waves-x-naked'
rr = requests.get(productpage)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(rr.content, 'xml')
productIDArray = soup1.find_all("div", class_="size-button property available")

#print for debugging purposes
print(productIDArray[0])
```

productIDArray[0] returns

```
<div class="size-button property available" data-productId="207789">
<span class="size-type" title="UK 3.5 | 36">
    US 4

        </span>
</div>
```

How would i grab the value of data-productID and the title of the span so that I can place them into variables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
productIDArray['data-productId']
```

out:

```
'207789'
```

---

```
productIDArray.span['title']
```

out:

```
'UK 3.5 | 36'
```